# Django Admin (the list of children in the form of editing a parent )

Tags: python, django

[image]

We need to edit in the Django Admin a list of ingredients of reciepe.

I can create ingredients one after another, but it's the bad idea. I want instead to add the list of ingredients of selected recipe in Django Admin form.

How to do it? I don't want to use 'inlines'.

Comment: why not inlines?  That is what they are for

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you adding to the list of recipes that use the given ingredient? Are you trying to add the ingredient to a list of other recipes?

Comment: 1) I want to add recipe in a single window, so I don't want to use inlines.

Comment: 2) I slightly changed the question. My model is following: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9630489/ I want to see a list of ingredients when edit recipe and add/edit recipe in a external window.